# Meeting Request Object, EWS, C#

Tags: c#, encoding, exchangewebservices

```
if (item.ItemClass.StartsWith("IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request"))
{                           
    fileName = exportDirectory + "download.dat";
    var meetingRequest = MeetingRequest.Bind(service, item.Id, props);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        fs.Write(meetingRequest.MimeContent.Content, 
        0,meetingRequest.MimeContent.Content.Length);
    }
 }
```

New to ews programming in c# and trying to pull down a MeetingRequest object to view it.   Not getting the object in clear text.   Is there a better object type to use on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to read the VCalendar part of the Meeting Request, EWS won't provide that seperatly to you but it is part of the MimeContent you already accessing so all you need to do is process the MIMEContent and save off that particular BodyPart. For that CDO can be used eg

```
            ADODB.Stream stream = new ADODB.Stream();
            stream.Type = ADODB.StreamTypeEnum.adTypeBinary;
            stream.Open(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeUnknown, ADODB.StreamOpenOptionsEnum.adOpenStreamUnspecified, null, null); 
            stream.Write(meetingRequest.MimeContent.Content); 
            stream.Position = 0;
            Message.DataSource.OpenObject(stream, "_Stream");
            foreach (CDO.IBodyPart bp in Message.BodyPart.BodyParts)
            {
                if (bp.ContentMediaType == "text/calendar") 
                {
                    bp.SaveToFile("c:\\temp\\calendarpart.txt");
                }
            }
```

Cheers
Glen